# What is the difference between contours and contours[0] when len(contours)=1?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, contour

I want to find the contours of an image to then draw its convex hull. What I am doing is loading the image, threshold it, find its contours and then draw the convex hull.

```
gray = cv2.imread(test_paths[i], 0)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnt = contours[0]
```

The number of contours detected is equal to 1.
The problem comes when I try to plot the contours, if I do

```
cv2.drawContours(cnt_dst, cnt, -1, (255, 0, 0), 3)
plt.imshow(cnt_dst)
```

[image]

If I change the code to the following:

```
cv2.drawContours(cnt_dst, contours, 0, (255, 0, 0), 3)
plt.imshow(cnt_dst)
```

The contours are different:

[image]

Note that I am getting the same (nice) result with this:

```
cv2.drawContours(cnt_dst, contours, -1, (255, 0, 0), 3)
```

Any ideas of why this is happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cv2.drawContours(cnt_dst, contours, 0, (255, 0, 0), 3)` or `cv2.drawContours(cnt_dst, contours, -1, (255, 0, 0), 3)` are the same in that case

`-1` tells opencv to draw *all* the contours of the contours array, and `0` tells it to draw the first contour of the contours array.

Since there's only one contour, the result is the same.

The other call `cv2.drawContours(cnt_dst, cnt, -1, (255, 0, 0), 3)` is probably bogus / should be better checked on the opencv side.

In [this blog](http://opencvpython.blogspot.fr/2012/06/hi-this-article-is-tutorial-which-try.html) it indicates:

> Now you want to draw "cnt" only. It can be done as follows:
>   cv2.drawContours(im,[cnt],0,(255,0,0),-1)
>   Note the square bracket around "cnt". Third argument set to 0, means only that particular contour is drawn.

Comment: `cv2.drawContours(cnt_dst, [cnt], -1, (255, 0, 0), 3)` made it. Thanks!